# Toggle player nametags on Ghost Recon

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

Somehow the tags that appear above teammates heads have disappeared. I have tried clicking the '-' key but that toggles the entire HUD. how can I get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was going into hud settings, turning it off and turning it back on.